# Check if a music (streamed from youtube) is playing on bot or not

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I just created a working queue command, but now Im stuck at editing the play command

I tried to make it that if a music is playing, the play command will only push the query to queue and wait for the music to finish playing then shift the queue to play next.

Im stuck at how to check whether the bot is still streaming a music from internet or not.

```js
//push function, stream and streamOptions is above from here
if (/*check whether a music is playing = false*/) {
   function dispatcher() {
       connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions)
       dispatcher.on('end', function () {
       lst.shiftlist(); //shift the queue
       if (lst.urllist[0]/*check if queue[0] contains*/) {
          dispatcher();
       }
       else {
          message.channel.send('Queue empty!');
          return;
       }
       })
   }
}
else if (/*check whether a music is playing = true*/) {
     message.channel.send('Added to queue!')
     console.log(url)
}
```

is it possible to check if the bot is still playing a stream or not? or is there any else method i can use for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the easiest way would be to toggle some kind of state when the music starts to play, and toggle it off when the dispatcher end event fires. Something like:

```
var playing = false
if (/*check whether a music is playing = false*/) {
   function dispatcher() {
       connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions)
       playing = true
       dispatcher.on('end', function () {
       lst.shiftlist(); //shift the queue
       if (lst.urllist[0]/*check if queue[0] contains*/) {
          dispatcher();
       }
       else {
          playing = false
          message.channel.send('Queue empty!');
          return;
       }
       })
   }
}
else if (/*check whether a music is playing = true*/) {
     message.channel.send('Added to queue!')
     console.log(url)
}
```

Comment: how can i be so narrow minded lol.
thx for this. very appreciated